# Filter DynamoDBScanExpression by Boolean attribute

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, boolean, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDBScanExpression that scans my table in DynamoDB service. The DB mapping class is `Item.class`. 

The reason I'm using `ScanExpression` is that it is an adapter to a ListView.

What I want to do, is to filter the `ScanExpression` results by `boolean`, so I'll get only the results where the attribute "text" will be `true`.

I've tried to check when the value of the attribute is equal to the String "true", but it didn't work.

```
DynamoDBScanExpression dbScanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression();
Condition condition = new Condition()
    .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.EQ)
    .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue("true"));
dbScanExpression.addFilterCondition("text", condition);
List<Item> itemsList = dbMapper.scan(Item.class, dbScanExpression);
```

How can I filter the ScanExpression to get only rows with `true` value in the "text" attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the field using the below annotation and scan the table as mentioned below (i.e. using new AttributeValue().withBOOL(true)).

```
@DynamoDBNativeBoolean
@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "text")
public Boolean getStatusCode() {
    return text;
}

Condition condition = new Condition().withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.EQ)
        .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withBOOL(true));
dbScanExpression.addFilterCondition("text", condition);
```